# how to implement sub domains in sitefinity 5.x

Tags: subdomain, sitefinity

On the sitefinity offcial website, there is only a guide for sitefinity 3.x which is too old.

Any one has any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if anyone else has figured this out, but here was my solution:

Sitefinity 5.3
IIS8
IIS Rewriting Module

Within your web.config, add the following to the end of the system.webServer node:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <!-- Redirect your page group to the base -->
    <rule name="Page Group Redirect" enabled="true">
      <match url="^sitefinitypagegroupname/(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <!-- Rewrite your sub domain to the page group -->
    <rule name="Page Group Rewrite" enabled="true">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.axd$" />
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="^/sitefinity(.*)" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?subdomain\.domain\.com$" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="sitefinitypagegroupname/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```